# Does PhoneGap's Media class support 3gpp?

Tags: android, cordova, audio

I use `navigator.device.capture.captureAudio` to record sound and get the file path. However, when I try to play it via Media.play(), it skips the whole block. Here's a snippet of my code for further info.

```
            navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(function(mediaFile){

                var checkerVar = "original value";

                var fullPath = mediaFile[0].fullPath;
                var mediaTest = new Media(fullPath, function(){
                    checkerVar = "new success value";
                    alert("Media loaded. Playing now.");
                    mediaTest.play();
                }, function(){
                    checkerVar = "new error value";
                    alert("Error with playback.");
                });

                alert(checkerVar);

            }, function(error){
                alert("Error:\n\n"+error);
            }, {limit: 1});
```

With the above code, I still get "original value" as prompt instead of either "new success value" or "new error value" which led me to believe it skips the whole block of `mediaTest`. I already tried getting the value of `fullPath` and it indeed shows the path to the newly recorded *.3gpp sound file. This leads me to question if it supports 3gpp at all?

If it doesn't support 3gpp, what are my options?

**EDIT:** So it supports 3gpp. Any idea why it skips the whole block of `var mediaTest` code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the format supported..

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile.getFormatData

yes it support 3gp too

Comment: So any clue why it skips that whole block of code without giving off any errors?